# How to create unique ID for Excel that meets certain requirement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

as a newbie Excel user, would like to ask how to create unique ID which fits the requirement.

Here is the summary sheet. Since want to add unique ID number (ID_004, ID_0005...) when the Column B(Step) is 1. It can be done by Excel formula or VBA, whether can be done. Thanks a lot...

[image: )]

Answer (score 1):

To preserve leading zeroes, construct an appropriate format mask for the TEXT function.

```
=IF(B2=1, TEXT(COUNTIF(B$2:B2, 1), "\I\D\_0000"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only requirement is a unique ID you could use the row number.

Like so (for cell A2):

```
=IF(B2=1;"ID_"&ROW(B2);"")
```

If the IDs need to increase consecutively. You could do:

```
=IF(B2=1;"ID_"&COUNTIF($B$2:B2;1);"")
```